# Google Crawler unable to crawl URLs with Whitespaces

Tags: web-crawler, http-status-code-404, google-search-console, googlebot

Google Search Console is reporting URLs with white spaces as responding with 404 response. It tells the source of such incomplete URLs to be from the sitemap. But having checked the sitemap the only thing common in such URLs is that the GoogleBot is parsing URLs by ignoring the part after the whitespace.

eg.

Actual URL in sitemap:

/hospital-search/Ahmedabad/Vascular Surgeon/true_/doc_/1

Reported URL which returns 404:

/hospital-search/Ahmedabad/Vascular

Answer (score 0):

Its recommended to replace the spaces with dashes, Google see the dashes as spaces in the text, also another thing it depends on your platform/framework, for example in PHP mywebsite.com/About-Us is different that mywebsite.com/about-us (with capital letter and small letter).

Try to test your link with both case (upper and lower) and see what the server will return to you, i think you will get 404 which also google get.

Its easy to solve this problem, change your URLs by replacing the spaces to dashes and unify all the words to lower case then redirect all your old links to the new one using 301 redirect and update your XML sitemap.

Answer (score 0):

why Google Crawler is unable to crawl your URLs is because you did not encode your spaces by `+` in your sitemap.

If you still want to use spaces - but not recommended as @Nadeem Haddadeen said - You should just replace spaces by `+` in your sitemap.
Like: `/hospital-search/Ahmedabad/Vascular+Surgeon/true_/doc_/1`.

Also recommended to have all small caps.